Npm instllation failing with npm ERR! E400
The below code was working fine till today and it suddenly failing with npm ERR E400
Using below node and npm versions
npm -v
 6.4.1
 + node -v
 v8.16.0



export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
export PHANTOMJS_CDNURL=http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/phantomjs/
export SASS_BINARY_SITE=http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/node-sass/

echo '{' >  .bowerrc
echo '   "registry": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "search": [ "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower" ],' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "resolvers":["bower-art-resolver"],' >>  .bowerrc
echo '   "proxy": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "http-proxy": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",'  .bowerrc
echo '   "https-proxy": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "directory": "vendor"'
echo '}' >>  .bowerrc
 
cat .bowerrc
 {
    "registry": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",
    "search": [ "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower" ],
    "resolvers":["bower-art-resolver"],
    "proxy": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",
    "http-proxy": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",
    "https-proxy": "http://user:password@artifactoryServer/artifactory/api/bower/bower",
    "directory": "vendor"
 }


 npm install bower-art-resolver

npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request: bower-art-resolver@^2.0.9
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2024-05-01T22_00_52_518Z-debug.log
I tried clearing cache and npm config set strict-ssl false and deleting the .npmrc file
But it did not work . Can some one help .
